# Stop setup from removing previous installation

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2019, settings, setup-project

I have a Winforms Desktop app solution to which I added a VS setup project.

I used the .msi it built to install the application on another PC.

I then updated my application, and re-built the setup.msi

When running that on the target PC it displays a prompt telling me to use the Control Panel to un-install the previous version.

Why does it do that?

How can I stop it?

The reason I don’t want to remove the previous installation is because the application uses a Settings page provided by WinForms, and I invoke the Update() method when first starting the new installation for the first time, so as to copy across user’s settings.
Thanks

Comment: it hard for us to keep the previous installation. However, I have a workaround about it. You can create a txt file to store the key information when we first install the app. Then, we can check if the file exists. If exists, we can read the file.

Comment: Removing the previous installation via the Control Panel doesn't remove its Settings - they get found OK by the new Installation. But it isn't a nice User Experience to be told to un-install a program just to update it to the newer version....